# When I use knitr to knit to html, there is no table output

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, kable

I am using `kableExtra` to try and output a LaTeX table but when I knit my code to `html`, the table does not output. It just outputs junk that I don't want. Example code is below, and a result of the output also:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

x <- seq(1,9,by = 1)

kable(x,format = 'latex', booktabs = T, caption = "A KnitR Kable")
```
````

Output in `html` file:

````
## 
## Attaching package: 'dplyr'
## The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
## 
##     filter, lag
## The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
## 
##     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```
````

What is going wrong?

Comment: change `format` to `format = 'html'` as you now ask knitr to produce Latex format

Comment: so changing that will still output table in latex format? I am new to this, so please bear with me. I need it to be in latex

Comment: If you want latex format then keep `format = 'latex'` but select knit -> knit to PDF to produce pdf which is compatible with Latex. Note you need to install Tex/Latex, I use Miktex which you can find [here](https://miktex.org/download) before rendering PDF

Comment: so I just download it, and then I am good to go? nothing to load into r like regular packages? @A.Suliman

Comment: Nothing in R but you will need some libraries in Miktex depending on your document. I think they will be installed in Miktex automatically while document gets rendering. If not and you get errors in R due to a missing library in MikTex then you can open Miktex Console and install it manually.

Comment: if you have time, can you take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120532/error-failed-to-compile-data-tex-execution-halted

Comment: Try `tinytex` https://github.com/yihui/tinytex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as the author of kableExtra, I feel like I need to do some clarification here. When you are using `knitr::kable` alone, what @JonGrub said is absolutely right. `format = "markdown"` in kable is the default and you will let pandoc determine the format of your table for you. However, if you are using `kableExtra`, which only works on either LaTeX or HTML table, those markdown outputs won't work. That's why in the past, you need to specify `format` in your kable call.

A few months ago, I realized that people have the need to generate a table that works in both HTML and LaTeX at the same time, especially with the popularity of `bookdown`. As a result, I added something to kableExtra in its 0.9.0 that it will automatically identify if it's used in a LaTeX environment. If so, it will set the default `kable` formats to be "latex". Otherwise, you will get a HTML table (if you are using it in a regular R session, you will see its preview in RStudio). This little trick allows you to get rid of those `format="xxx"` calls. It allows you to generate customized table output using the same piece of code that works in both HTML and LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments pointed out the problem here is that you are using `format = 'latex'` while you are using R-markdown to knit to a `html` report. R-markdown uses the markdown language though instead of Latex when producing `html`.

The picture looks different when you produce a PDF since the process then produces a Latex document first which is compiled with latex.

To get the chunk, you will thus have to choose `format = 'markdown'`. This will work for both html and PDF. However, I would suggest you don't specify the format at all since `rmarkdown` will choose the format for you. The second problem you mention is that `dplyr` startup message is shown. You can turn this off using `message = FALSE` in your chunk options. So I would suggest:

````
```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

x <- seq(1, 9, by = 1)

kable(x, booktabs = TRUE, caption = "A KnitR Kable")
```
````

Another good tip is to try using the `render()` command from `rmarkdown` if you have problems using knit from RStudio directly. It often makes errors more explicit. This is the syntax:

```
rmarkdown::render("C:/path/to/file.Rmd", output_format = "all")
```

Note, that you can specify the output file format here. All means that all output formats specified in your header will be produced. For example:

```
---
title: ''
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```

In this case the above command will output a html as well as PDF file. If you can't output PDF files, most likely you are missing a latex installation. I second @Tung recommendation of `tinytex`, but you can also look into Miktex or Texlive.

Edit: Thanks to @camille's comment I realised `format = 'latex'` works fine when knitting to PDF and will only misbehave when knitting to html.

Comment: The problem isn't that they're using `format = "latex"` in an Rmarkdown document, it's that they're using `format = "latex"` but trying to knit to html. You can set a table to latex and knit to PDF—I believe that's what `knitr` would do behind the scenes if you didn't specify a table format but knit to PDF

Comment: Thanks. I tested knitting to a PDF and you are right. I remember reading somewhere that `rmarkdown` will produce a .tex file first and compile this instead of an .md file.  I guess that's the reason why this works?